# Special characters in URL for DB selection

Tags: php

I am trying to use special `danish` characters (æøå) in the URL as GET parameters. So for instance I have this URL:

```
     http://example.com?name=åge
```

that URL will get converted into the ASCII equivalent automatically, so in the URL it will read:

```
    http://example.com?name=%E5ge
```

When i access and print out that value it works just fine, and displays that parameter as:
åge

However, i am using that to select stuff in my DB, and this won't work. If i use the ASCII version in the URL, it won't select anything form the DB and just give me an empty result. If i force the URL to not use ASCII, so it is: `http://example.com?name=åge` it will work fine when selecting from the DB, but when I display the parameter it shows as this:
`Ã¥`

I have no idea how to get around this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `%E5` is not ASCII but ISO-8859-1. (ASCII is 7bit only.) You should be using UTF-8 instead, both in URL-encoding the request (å → `%C3%A5`) and in your output handling (`Ã¥` is what \xC3\xA5 looks when interpreted as latin1). Your DB is doing the right thing.

Comment: oh okay, but how do i do this then?

If i am making a link like this:
<a href="http://example.com?name=åge />

Then the link will use the ISO encoding you talked about, converting the å into %E5. So how do i force it to use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: The browser should normally use UTF-8 encoding itself (MSIE 5.0 has a config option for that, which is normally turned off though; dunno about newer versions). If you deliver your page as UTF-8 in the first place, the browsers might get a clue. I’ve not seen browsers not encode as UTF-8 in like forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transform the parameter to UTF-8 and then prepare the database for a UTF-8 query, with something like this:

```
$name = utf8_encode($_GET['name']);
mysqli_query($mysqli_connector, "SET NAMES UTF8");
```

And then, prepare your query.

That should work.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Ah that did the trick. I have the encode / decode manually when i am working with these characters. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Although, it is still showing it like this: Ã¥ even after the decoding? It works when i throw it into the DB (dunno why) but it still displays like that on the page? any ideas?

Comment: Charsets are always a problem when coding websites. From my experience I always set the Database, the files encoding and the HTML to UTF-8

In your case, if you have developed a lot... I don't know. Try with encoding/decoding or change the html code to utf8

<meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: ah, the <meta charset> fixed it. I just assumed HTML5 documents had that as a default. Guess not. :)