# mysql query not working as expected (encoding?)

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

i'm running virtuemart on my joomla web - here's my code:

```
$session_id = "aaa";
$quantity = 5;
$newid = 123;
$deli = "\0\0\0";
$data = '"Joomla\Registry\Registry":1:{s:7:"'.$deli.'data";O:8:"stdClass":0:{}}s:4:"user";O:5:"JUser":25:{s:9:"'.$deli.'isRoot";b:0;s:2:"id";i:0;s:4:"name";N;s:8:"username";N;s:5:"email";N;s:8:"password";N;s:14:"password_clear";s:0:"";s:5:"block";N;s:9:"sendEmail";i:0;s:12:"registerDate";N;s:13:"lastvisitDate";N;s:10:"activation";N;s:6:"params";N;s:6:"groups";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"9";}s:5:"guest";i:1;s:13:"lastResetTime";N;s:10:"resetCount";N;s:12:"requireReset";N;s:10:"'.$deli.'_params";O:24:"Joomla\Registry\Registry":1:{s:7:"'.$deli.'data";O:8:"stdClass":0:{}}s:14:"'.$deli.'_authGroups";a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:9;}s:14:"'.$deli.'_authLevels";a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:5;}s:15:"'.$deli.'_authActions";N;s:12:"'.$deli.'_errorMsg";N;s:10:"'.$deli.'_errors";a:0:{}s:3:"aid";i:0;}}__vm|a:2:{s:6:"manage";i:0;s:6:"vmcart";s:632:"{"cartProductsData":[{"virtuemart_product_id":'.$newid.',"quantity":'.$quantity.',"customProductData":[]}],"vendorId":1,"lastVisitedCategoryId":0,"virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id":"3","virtuemart_paymentmethod_id":0,"automaticSelectedShipment":true,"automaticSelectedPayment":false,"order_number":null,"BT":0,"ST":0,"cartfields":null,"couponCode":"","_triesValidateCoupon":[],"order_language":"de-DE","pricesCurrency":47,"paymentCurrency":null,"_guest":1,"_inCheckOut":false,"_inConfirm":false,"_dataValidated":false,"_confirmDone":false,"STsameAsBT":1,"selected_shipto":0,"_fromCart":false,"layout":"default","layoutPath":"","virtuemart_cart_id":0}";}';
$sq = "update c09ar_session set data='".$data."' WHERE session_id='".$session_id."'";

$db = new mysqli($host,$username,$pass,$dbname);
$db->set_charset("utf8");
$db->query($sq);
```

the problem is the delimiter variable $deli, its data won't be stored as expected.

after running the query and checking in phpmyadmin, the string snippet \0\0\0 will be replaced with a strange character (see image)[image]
when pasting the string using phpmyadmin, i can see \0\0\0 as expected.

any ideas what's wrong with my syntax?
i already tried changing the delimiter to:

```
$deli = "\\0\\0\\0";
```

didn't help ..
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special characters in URL for DB selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921207/special-characters-in-url-for-db-selection)

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement before executing yours. It sets the codification to utf-8

```
mysqli_query($mysqli_connector, "SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help :(
seems like it's the same as using set_charset (which i already set to utf8) - here'sy my code:
$db = new mysqli($host,$username,$pass,$dbname);
$db->set_charset("utf8");
when using your snippet it still stores the characters wrong .. any idea? :(